# Couldn't able to access the client access token from Dialog Flow, I need to use in Angular Application

Tags: angular, api, client, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I was a newbie, started developing a sample chatbot using angular and DialogFlow, I was not able to access the client access token. And I have tried other ways like gcloud auth print access token, and have gone through Google service account. Any answer is welcome, Thanks in advance.

[image: Here is the picture of Dialog- flow account]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dialogflow v2 no longer uses developer/client access tokens. Those were for v1 only.

You need to [setup authentication](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup#auth) and download private keys now to access the API endpoints.

If you are using a library, you should just be able to [make the downloaded keys available](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/setup#auth-env) to your library. If you are doing it yourself, you will need to generate an OAuth 2 auth token using these keys.

Comment: I have downloaded the private key JSON file from services, which contains the private key, id. So from that file how can we get the client access token?

Comment: As I said - you don't use access tokens anymore. I've updated the answer to provide another link about how to use the dowloaded keys, but there are also lots of other answers that specifically address this point.

Comment: Okay, Thankyou. @Prisoner